# Why won't wordpress load the javascript file on a different server?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, include

I'm loading js in wordpress this way:

```
function add_my_user_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('myScriptsjs_user',plugins_url('/js/myScriptsjs_user.js', __FILE__),'','',true);
        wp_localize_script( 'myScriptsjs_user', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    }
```

I need the myAjax for the files ajax call. This works on my test server but once I load it to the live server it js won't load. Everything else loads fine on the live server including the css. I turned off the other plugins (still have the issue) and spit out the php errors and I don't get any conflicts.

I looked at my other plugins that use ajax and I did it the same way... loads fine. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Something obvious: Is file present on that server?

Comment: yes, I even had the server output plugins_url('/js/myScriptsjs_user.js', __FILE__). I copied the url it gave me and was able to see the file contents on the server.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have 3.5 on my dev server and 3.6 running on the live server. I doubt that would cause this issue though. 3.6 really just included more security than anything else.

Comment: That code is invalid JavaScript code.  Run it through JSHint.

Comment: What is `array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ))` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're facing a problem of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). It happens to me more than once using Ajax and you only realize this once you push your code on non-local servers. You can read more on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2851187/970247). Hope this will help solve your problem.