# Facebook Graph API getting JSON using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is my first time using Facebook in jQuery.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 
www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=20531316728&format=JSON
    &callback=jQuery110105899784066714346_1383828332964&_=1383828332965:2
```

Code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=20531316728&format=JSON',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sreekeshokky/WFQ4J/)

Why am I getting this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851164/making-an-ajax-request-to-another-server

Comment: I'm already using 'jsonp'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why doesn't it work?

jQuery, being a Javascript framework, must apply the implementation rules for Ajax requests, more specifically the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) one. Briefly, this restriction says that Ajax requests can only be performed towards the same domain.

This information can also be found in the jQuery [`$.ajax` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

### Workaround

#### YQL: Yahoo Query Language

> The Yahoo Query Language is an expressive SQL-like language that lets
>   you query, filter, and join data across Web services. With YQL, apps
>   run faster with fewer lines of code and a smaller network footprint.
>
> Source: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

#### Using YQL as a proxy

YQL can be used as a proxy in order to make a cross-domain Ajax call possible. Explanations can be found here: [JavaScript: Use a Web Proxy for Cross-Domain XMLHttpRequest Calls](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)

#### Code

```
var fbUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=20531316728&format=JSON";

$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        q: 'select * from json where url="' + fbUrl + '"',
        format: "json"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.query.results.json.entries, function (i, v) {
            $('#entries').append(data.query.results.json.entries[i].title + '<br />');
        });
    }
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WFQ4J/4/)</kbd>

Comment: The result of YQL is gibberish.

Comment: The result shows the titles of the posts one by one. How is that gibberish? *You* have to select the information you need.

Comment: The titles are limited to some length only.

Comment: The `title` field is already truncated by Facebook in the original JSON.