# YQL Facebook Table possible?

Tags: facebook, yql

Is it possible to use YQL for facebook? I know there are tables for twitter but I don't see a facebook one which makes me wonder if it is possible. I also did't see any tutorials for facebook.

Comment: I guess you could use YQL, but this yould only work for publically available info. Even then it's not transparent to me why you'd to an intermediate step instead of calling the FB API directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, why not? Here is an example.

```
var fbUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=20531316728&format=JSON";

$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        q: 'select * from json where url="' + fbUrl + '"',
        format: "json"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.query.results.json.entries, function (i, v) {
            $('#entries').append(data.query.results.json.entries[i].title + '<br />');
        });
    }
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WFQ4J/4/)</kbd>

Note that it also helps [getting JSON from Facebook using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836796/facebook-graph-api-getting-json-using-ajax/19860830#19860830).